# How to update a data source in parent from a user control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, datasource

I have an asp.net 4 page with a user control in it. When the user selects a value in a grid inside the user control I would like to update a data source's (in my case a LINQ data source) WHERE clause using a value from the grid. The data source object is in the parent page. The page life cycle loads the parent page before the grid's item command method executes so I am not able to get the selected value.

How can this be done? I would like to do this all server-side if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an event in the child page like so:

```
public event EventHandler DataChanged;
```

From the child page, call it like this when appropriate:

```
if (DataChanged != null)
    DataChanged(sender, new EventArgs());
```

Then in the parent page, create a method to be called and attach it like so:

```
protected void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

child.DataChanged += DoSomething;
```

Oh yeah, I almost forgot.  I think you have to set up the event relationship in Page_Init() rather than waiting for Page_Load().

Comment: @RoastBeast Glad I could help, enjoy!